# Primefaces p:editor component removes tags <html>,<head> and <body> on value change event

Tags: primefaces, editor, text-editor

I have code:

```
<p:editor id="selectedTemplateBody" value="#{tabBean.body}" height="430"
      widgetVar="editTemplate" onchange="saveHtml();"
      controls="bold italic underline font size style color highlight rule
        bullets numbering alignleft center alignright justify undo redo source"/>
<p:remoteCommand name="saveHtml" process="@parent" update="@none"/>
```

And the `tabBean.body` var contains text (loaded form DB) with html-tags `<html>,<head> and <body>` by default. When I do any change of the value in VIEW-window of editor, it leads to removing all that tags from SOURCE-window of editor and it changes `tabBean.body` of course.

How do I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

try the attribute **escape=false** of the editor component.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Uwe Keim... I tried to suggest and I dont think any suggestion can be deleted. I believe it can be down voted. Please correct me if I am wrong. And can you suggest the answer of the question mentioned above since it will help me learn something too...

Comment: Сomponent does not have attribute "escape"